# What is the best way to install required packages for SFDX package before sfdx force:source:push?

Tags: salesforcedx

The sfdx-project.json contains a list of packages on which your packages depends, and there are scripts available to perform installation of dependencies such as the one available here:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_install_pkg_sample_script.htm
- https://medium.com/salesforce-dev-cafe/sfdx-create-a-complex-dev-org-with-one-line-in-terminal-52cfa530f0be

However, while the first script requires that your code is already released as a package (and it will use a SOQL query to determine the dependency of your package) the second script requires you to specify the packageID you depend on as an environment variable.

Since those packages ids are specified in your sfdx-project.json, isn't there an sfdx command to install those packages, providing a list of installation keys?

Comment: Include the installedpackages meta and push ? Or use the mdapi commands?

Answer (score 3):

We've build a custom sfdx plugin that does just that. It parses your sfdx-project.json and install all the dependencies listed.

Just run the following:

```
sfdx texei:package:dependencies:install -u MyScratchOrg -k "1:MyPackage1Key 2: 3:MyPackage3Key"
```

and all dependencies will be installed, using the provided Installation Keys.

You can install the plugin running `sfdx plugins:install texei-sfdx-plugin`

I also wrote a blog post about this, you can have a look [here](https://blog.texei.com/automatically-install-second-generation-packages-dependencies-with-a-custom-sfdx-plugin-36ec83130457).