# Install 3rd party app into a Scratch Org using sfdx

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, scratch-org

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to include a 3rd party managed package into a Scratch Org as part of a project deployment.

The 3rd party app is [CalendarAnything](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Hn2kEAC)

Reading through [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262479/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-required-packages-for-sfdx-package-before-sfdx-f/263781) and [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) it seems that I would need to include the dependency definition in my sfdx-project.json

```js
"dependencies": [ 
      {
        "package": "OtherOrgPackage@1.2.0"
      }
  ]
```

How would I work out the package name and version from the AppExchange listing and how does this work with paid apps anyway?